# What is the best way to override Mage/Core/functions.php in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-core

Magento has an elegant way to override it's modules. But what I have done till now is override Blocks, Models, Helpers and controllers.
But this file

> Mage/Core/functions.php

doesn't appear to fall in any of those categories. Is there any elegant way to override this other than putting it in *local codepool*?

I want to change the error log messages(system and exception) and populate them with session and IP so that I can get a better knowledge about the users who received the errors.

Comment: just interested: can you give a little more detail what you need to achieve?

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 3):

If I can see this correctly, `Mage_Core_Model_App` has this constant:

```
const DEFAULT_ERROR_HANDLER = 'mageCoreErrorHandler';
```

...which is later registered like this:

```
/**
 * Initialize PHP environment
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_App
 */
protected function _initEnvironment()
{
    $this->setErrorHandler(self::DEFAULT_ERROR_HANDLER);
    date_default_timezone_set(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::DEFAULT_TIMEZONE);
    return $this;
}
```

You can override this class in a module and either change the constant to your custom method name, or modify `_initEnvironment()` to register another error handler.

**==EDIT==**

As pointed out in @Brat's comment, this function can not be overridden... however, here's an alternative approach. It's untested, and I have no idea if it can work :)

Referencing [Alan Storm](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/32402056167/magento-startup-events), these are the earliest events you can listen to:

```
resource_get_tablename    
core_collection_abstract_load_before
core_collection_abstract_load_after
controller_front_init_before
```

Maybe you can do something like this in your observer:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer {
    function customErrorHandler($o) {
        if(function_exists('mageCoreErrorHandler') {
            require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../functions.php');
            Mage::app()->setErrorHandler("myErrorHandler");
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then place a file functions.php in `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/functions.php` and define `myErrorHandler()` there.

Or even another possibility: In the same observer, use [runkit_function_remove()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-remove.php) and re-define `mageCoreErrorHandler()` in your own `functions.php`-file.

Comment: Overriding Mage_Core_Model_App won't work. It's hardcoded in Mage.php

Comment: Updated my answer; untested, though